# Can I get the Tumbleweed badge if my question has votes, but net score is 0?

Tags: discussion, badges, tumbleweed-badge

The description of the Tumbleweed badge says:

> Asked a question with zero score, no answers, no comments, and low
>   views for a week.

If I get 1 up-vote and 1 down-vote, then the total score is 0.

Am I still eligible for the Tumbleweed badge?

Comment: Yes, that's what zero score means

Comment: so after a week it must have total 0 score?

Comment: What exactly do you find unclear? Do you feel you should have such a badge for some question?

Comment: I am just confused about same number of up and down vote makes it zero. and that is correct for tumbleweed or just no votes?

Comment: Score 0 means `# of upvotes === # of downvotes`.

Comment: Actually you might have a point. The [unofficial faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) says "Ask a question that receives **no votes**, no answers, no comments and no more than 60 views in its first week of existence" - this is different from "zero score". @Oded can you please verify what is correct here?

Comment: Anyway, this is dupe - once the issue will be clarified (hopefully by Oded) we can just edit the faq

Comment: @ShadowWizard - the query looks at score. Doesn't look at voting at all.

Comment: Thanks @Oded, will fix the faq then.

Comment: @ShadowWizard  how can this be duplicated question?? there is nothing in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions this question related to my question.

Comment: @Eirenaios the answer there answers your question as well: yes, you can get the badge in those conditions.